# Why is Redirect not working in my shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I'm trying to find keywords and redirect them to file. I can see the results on the terminal but those results are not redirected in the txt file.

```
find /opt/IBM /opt/ibm /usr/IBM /usr/ibm \( -name db2licm -o -name onstat -o -name versionInfo.sh -o -name WPVersionInfo.sh \) 2>>/tmp/versiondocument.txt
```

I expect the path of `db2licm`, `versioninfo.sh` in `versiondocument.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only redirect the errors by using `2>>`. Try the following example:

```sh
$ find
.
./b
./b/file.txt
./b/b.txt
./a
./a/a.txt
./a/c.txt
./tmp.log
$ find a b -name file.txt -o -name a.txt >> tmp.log
$ cat tmp.log 
a/a.txt
b/file.txt
```

Comment: You need to escape parens

Comment: As you can see, in OP's invocation parens (`)(`) are escaped, but in yours they're not, and you're saying it's OP's mistake

Comment: @oguzismail No, the first post (before the edit) didn't have the escaped `()`. Therefore my answer was valid :p I've removed it anyhow.

Comment: Okay then, removed mine